# Row column operation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

[image]

I want to get a result from this table as follows. How can I do it in SQL Server?

[image]

Output when using Case When

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when col1 = 'a' then e end) as a_e,
       max(case when col1 = 'a' then f end) as a_f,
       max(case when col1 = 'a' then g end) as a_g,
       max(case when col1 = 'b' then e end) as b_e,
       max(case when col1 = 'b' then f end) as b_f,
       max(case when col1 = 'b' then g end) as b_g,
       max(case when col1 = 'c' then e end) as c_e,
       max(case when col1 = 'c' then f end) as c_f,
       max(case when col1 = 'c' then g end) as c_g,
       max(case when col1 = 'd' then e end) as d_e,
       max(case when col1 = 'd' then f end) as d_f,
       max(case when col1 = 'd' then g end) as d_g
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've tried this before, but it doesn't give the exact result I want. Returns unmatched records as NULL.

Comment: I added the output to the question. As you can see there, NULL values are returned when Case When is used.

Comment: @uckocaman . . . Conditional *aggregation* is not aggregation unless aggregation functions are used.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your interest and responses.